# Why does --text="$@" only pass the first word?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

When I run the following script with some arguments like `arg1 arg2 arg3`:

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --entry --text="$@"
```

zenity creates an entry dialog with this text: "arg1" whereas I expect "arg1 arg2 arg3"

If I use a variable like the following script it shows all arguments for the entry text.

```
#!/bin/bash
text="$@"
zenity --entry --text="$text"
```

What's the difference between these scripts? Why does the first one replace `$@` with the first argument only?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$@` expands to separate words (whereas `$*` expands to a single word), as explained in the [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html).  Thus, when you write

```
zenity --text="$@"
```

it expands to

```
zenity --text="$1" "$2" "$3"
```

However, shell variable assignments do not undergo word splitting.  Note that field / word splitting is omitted in the list of expansions for variable assignments in the [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html).  This behavior is consistent with the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01).  So, when you write

```
text="$@"
```

the variable `text` gets all of the positional parameters as a single word, equivalent to if you had written `text="$*"`.  Indeed, this is the reason double quotes are often unnecessary in variable assignments.  Both

```
text=$@
```

and

```
text=$*
```

are perfectly safe.

So,

```
text=$@
zenity --option="$text"
```

expands `"$text"` to a single word, which is why this works.  Note that the `--option="$@"` is just a normal argument to the command `zenity`, and not a shell variable assignment, which is why word splitting takes place here but not in `text=$@`.

Comment: +1. This will also work: `zenity --text="$*"` -- `"$*"` expands to a single word.

Comment: +1 for teaching me one thing: man != documentation. I should had searched info bash, it also contains the manual section you linked to.

Answer (score 7):

`$@` get expanded each parameter in separate word, becoming

```
zenity --entry --text="arg1" "arg2" "arg3" # syntactically wrong for zenity
```

Use `$*` instead to expand it in a single word

```
zenity --entry --text="$*"
```

which will become

```
zenity --entry --text="arg1 arg2 arg3" # syntactically correct for zenity
```

Comment: Please shed light on why the $text variant from the OP's question works as expected

Comment: @ChandraRavoori, you caught me with that. According to the manual “Word splitting is not performed, with the exception of "$@"” and “If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word.”, so I would expect `text="$@"` to be expanded to `text="arg1" "arg2" "arg3"`, which should fail. But certainly is not the case.

Comment: @ChandraRavoori The reason is field splitting doesn't happen in variable assignments.  I explain in more detail in my [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52998/9537).

Comment: @jw013: But according to the *Bash Reference Manual*, `"$@"` *does* undergo word splitting, *even* in variable assignments.

Comment: @ruakh The bash manual doesn't say that as far as I know.  Do  you have a quote?

Comment: @jw013: See manatwork's comment above. His first quote, `Word splitting is not performed, with the exception of "$@"`, comes from the explanation of the processing of the right-hand-side of variable assignments. (Just search http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html for that string.)

Comment: @ruakh Hmm, you are right.  The language and context there does seem to suggest that `$@` undergoes word-splitting in assignments, but that contradicts actual `bash` behavior as well as the POSIX spec.  Perhaps this is a bug in the manual?  I am not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @jw013 It might have to do with assigning it into an array variable?

Comment: @Random832 that's true, `var=("$@")` does undergo word splitting.  The manual could probably be a bit clearer about what it means there.